# HTML5: Should only heading be wrapped in header?

Tags: html

If a header section contains only heading (eg. h1, h2..), and no other information. Should it still be wrapped it in the header tags? Or the header tags should be used if it has more content than just the headings?

For example, should this be used?

```
<section>
    <h2> .... </h2>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

or this?

```
<section>
    <header>
        <h2>...</h2>
    </header>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In addition to calling for opinions rather than technical answers backed up with facts and specs, the question is based on a misunderstanding. HTML5 doesn’t suggest the use of `section` for page headers but for parts of content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm not using section for the page headers. I'm using it in the content area. In above example, a content div has multiple sections, each section having a heading and multiple articles wrapped in a div. Also, since there's no technical specification for the tag, so i asked this question to get the opinion of the experts.

Comment: Fair enough, I misunderstood part of the question. The intended question seems to be “if a section has just a heading and no other header content, should the heading element still be wrapped in a `header` element?” This is still a call for opinions and debate, not for solutions to specific problems. (As a matter of expert opinion, the `header` element solves no problems, but other experts surely disagree. Most of them probably regard such use as redundant, but this is really a matter of opinion.)

Comment: According to the HTML5 specification `<header>` element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an `<h1>`-`<h6>` element or an `<hgroup>` element), but this is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's that HTML5 doctor article:

[Avoiding common HTML5 mistakes](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/)

...as [linked to by @simoncereska](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669505/922323).

To save folks some time, here's the relevant quote:

> **If your `<header>` element only contains a single heading element, leave
>   out the `<header>`.** The `<article>` (for example) ensures that the heading will be shown
>   in the document outline, and because the `<header>` doesn’t contain
>   multiple elements (as the definition describes), why write code when
>   you don't need to? Simply use this:
>
> ```
> <article>  
>     <h1>My best blog post</h1>
>     <!-- Article content -->
> </article>
> ```

The article is definitely worth reading, but if your looking for a quick answer, then see the bold text in the above quote. :)